# How can I draw A and I letter in WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I get the right shape when I use `gl.LINE_LOOP` but when I try to use `gl.TRIANGLE_FAN` I get an odd looking shape. I have attached my vertices as well.

```
vertices = new Float32Array([
   0,    0,      0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
   0,    0.7,    0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
   0.5,  0.7,    0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
   0.5,  0.6,    0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
   0.2,  0.6,    0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
   0.2,  0.5,    0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
   0.5,  0.5,    0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
   0.5,  0.4,    0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
   0.2,  0.4,    0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
   0.2,  0,    0.0, 1.0, 1.0
]);


rect1 = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, rect1 );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW );

var FSIZE = vertices.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;

// Associate out shader variables with our data buffer

var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, FSIZE * 5, 0 );
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);

var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vVertexColor");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, FSIZE * 5, FSIZE * 2);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vColor);

gl.drawArrays( gl.LINE_LOOP, 0, 10 );
```